# Kohana - validation issue

Tags: model, controller, kohana

Recently I started with Kohana and everything is fine to the moment, but I have a question:

Where I should do my form validations (registration form as example) in the controller or in the model? I saw examples in kohana's documentation and they used the controller to do these things, but I find that it's more confortable for me to do them in the model. Is it wrong or ..?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in an MVC architecture, always aim to have fat models. everything else should be slim.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have ANY "fat" classes. Fat classes means you have too much code in there, and the class is likely violating SRP. Don't restrict your classes to MVC and you'll be much better off.

Things like validation belong in *their own* class, and used by your business logic.